# Share information when Bigquery data is up-to-date with users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I'm looking for the best place to store information when data from Bigquery table is ready for export and table is up-to-date - ready for user's queries. This information should be accesible for business users and external applications (checking will be performed e.g. every 5 minutes).

I'm going to use Cloud Composer as data workflow orchestration service but Composer metadata in Cloud SQL is accesible only for user who created Composer instance.

What are best practices to share such a data with users?

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a functional requirement. Si why not at the end of each integration you add a new record in a data store.  Then make that data accessible by business users. Or you can use a store like Cloud Firestore, and when you add or modify a record you can trigger a Cloud Function that can send an email.